# Console logging not logging variables in Maestro

Tags: maestro

While debugging API calls I'm making in a script within a Maestro flow, I've discovered that `console.log()`, which is supported in Maestro as of 1.26.1, doesn't seem to be working as expected - the variable passed in as a second parameter in the example below doesn't log, even if the variable is declared right before the `console.log`:

```js
const myValue = 'hey'
console.log('My hardcoded value is:', myValue) // only logs 'My hardcoded value is:'
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong/of a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the answer to this lies in, as the docs state,

> Maestro supports a minimal subset of vanilla JavaScript APIs

Maestro is running a very limited version of JS, and one of the things that's unsupported is the `console.log(msg, obj)` syntax of `console.log`.

So

`console.log('My variable', myVariable)`

fails, but if you do:

`console.log(myVariable)`

it works.

*(Update: Maestro now has [beta support for GraalJS](https://maestro.mobile.dev/advanced/javascript/graaljs-support), which may also resolve the issue.)*

Answer (score 1):

My issue was with the reporter. If you're running in reporter mode, or multiple flows (maestro will put into reporter mode for you), then console logs won't work. So if you need to see console logs, use

```
maestro test SINGLE_FLOW_NAME.yaml
```

instead of

```
maestro test /flows/*
```